# Rails Create has_record? for a nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

I've two models

```
  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :review
  end

  class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
  end
```

Now I would like to have this method in Article

```
  class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :review

    def self.has_review?

    end

  end
```

I've tried with .count, .size....but I've errors...how can I do to have the following code working

```
@article = Article.find(xxx)
if @article.has_revew?
 ....
else
 ...
end
```

The reason why I need it is becaus I will have different action in views or controller, if there is one Review or none

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :review

  def has_review?
    !!review
  end
end
```

This just defines a method on the instance (`def self.method` defines a class method). The method tries to load `review`. If the `review` does not exist, it will be nil. `!!` just inverts it twice, returning true if a review exists or false if the review is `nil`.

Comment: Thanks...last option, if the Review has a scope and I would like to check with the scope for example scope :active, {:conditions => {:approved => true}}